# Store total online users in RRDtool given login/logout, checkin/checkout logs

Tags: logfiles, rrdtool

Given a log file with clear check-in and check-out messages per user, how can I feed this data into RRDtool to track the total users logged in to the site? (At this time, I do not care about unique users, but that would be nice too of course!)

I read about the DERIVE data source type. How do I get a hypothetical INTEGRAL type instead? Can this be done straightforwardly?

Of course, I could process the file myself, updating GAUGE into the RRD and saving state somehow.; however, I am hoping to avoid that if I can get away with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since rrdtool deals in 'rates' it can not really count as you would like it to. The best you could get would be to use an ABSOLUTE type data-source, but this would only work for creating something like a login/logout rate statistic ... you could answer how many logins and how many logouts per-hour you had ...

You would then do an `rrdtool update login.rrd N:1`  whenever you have a login.

Comment: Thanks, Tobi! I have long since done what you said (the question is a bit old) however it's great to finally get some confirmation.